# Bad tab format in activity page when recieving a new response

Tags: bug, design, activity-tab

I recently noticed a bad format of tabs in the profile section. The horizontal line below the response tab is no more visible when I have a new response notification.

Take a look at what I mean:

[image: Image showing Responses tab bug]

Also on reputation tab:

[image: Reputation tab bug]

Is this by design, or is it actually a bug?

Web Browser = Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit).